# How to asynchronously abort a solve in docplex?

Tags: python, docplex

I have 2 simultaneous solves running using docplex and I want to stop one of the solve as soon as the other one finishes. Is there an way to end one solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I was able to add the feature using below code:

````
from docplex.mp.progress import ProgressListener, ProgressClock
class AutomaticAborter(ProgressListener):
    """ a simple implementation of an automatic search stopper.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(AutomaticAborter, self).__init__(ProgressClock.All)
        self.last_obj = None
        self.last_obj_time = None
        self.con = 0
        
    def notify_start(self):
        super(AutomaticAborter, self).notify_start()
        self.last_obj = None
        self.last_obj_time = None    
        self.con = 0
    def is_improving(self, new_obj, eps=1e-4):
        last_obj = self.last_obj
        return last_obj is None or (abs(new_obj- last_obj) >= eps)
            
    def notify_progress(self, pdata):
        super(AutomaticAborter, self).notify_progress(pdata)
        global con_f
        if pdata.has_incumbent and self.is_improving(pdata.current_objective):
            self.last_obj = pdata.current_objective
            self.last_obj_time = pdata.time
            print('----> #new objective={0}, time={1}s'.format(self.last_obj, self.last_obj_time))
        else:
            # a non improving move
            last_obj_time = self.last_obj_time
            this_time = pdata.time
            if last_obj_time is not None:
                self.con=con_f
                if con_f>0:
                    print('!! aborting cplex, con_f >{}'.format(self.con))
                    self.abort()
                else:
                    print('----> running {}'.format(con_f))
con_f=0

solver.add_progress_listener(AutomaticAborter())
solver1.add_progress_listener(AutomaticAborter())

def work(worker_queue, id, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():

        if id==1:
            work.msol=solver.solve(clean_before_solve=True,log_output=True)
        else:
            work.msol1=solver1.solve(clean_before_solve=True,log_output=True)
        # put worker ID in queue
        if not stop_event.is_set():
            worker_queue.put(id)
        break
# queue for workers
worker_queue = Queue()

# indicator for other threads to stop
stop_event = threading.Event()

# run workers
threads = []
threads.append(Thread(target=work, args=(worker_queue, 1, stop_event)))
threads.append(Thread(target=work, args=(worker_queue, 2, stop_event)))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
# this will block until the first element is in the queue
first_finished = worker_queue.get()

print(first_finished, 'was first!')

con_f=1


# signal the rest to stop working
stop_event.set()```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the low-level engine object that is returned by the `get_cplex()` function. This is an instance of the [Cplex](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html?pos=2) class of the [CPLEX Python API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/help.html). You can install an [Aborter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.aborter.Aborter-class.html) into that instance using function [use_aborter()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html?view=kc#use_aborter).

If you use the same aborter for all `Cplex` instances then you can eventually call the aborters `abort()` function to stop all the solves.

Note that the request to abort is not always handled immediately. There may be a small delay before the CPLEX engine acknowledges the abort.

Comment: Thank you, but do you have some example of this. I tried adding solver.get_cplex(cplex.Cplex().use_aborter(cplex.Aborter().abort())) to thread as soon as it completes but it doesn't seems to be working

Comment: You have to install the aborter *before* you start the solve and keep a reference to that aborter. Then, when you want to abort the solve you call that aborter's `abort()` method. You can take a look at the `mipex4.py` example that ships with cplex (of course you should call `abort()` way later than in this example).